# Picklist value check not working

Tags: apex, picklist, dependent-picklist, loop

I have below code snippet here where I am not getting if clause work properly. Can someone please help? Outcome_abv__c is a picklist value. I can't find any picklist value as '--None--' it comes up during scroll for null.

```
       For(Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c  o : citlist)
      {if(o.Outcome_abv__c=='--None--') // Not working
          {ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please select outcome before Coach!');

        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        Outcomecheck=true;
        o.Control_R_C_abv__c=false;
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is behaving as expected. --None-- is only displayed on the UI, and it comes over as a blank string. `if(o.Outcome_abv__c=='')`